# Why are my numbers not calculating correctly in my Number Guessing game?

Tags: c++, function, int, double, arithmetic-expressions

Why are my numbers not calculating correctly? My teacher wouldn't give me more help because he thought it was close enough to his output. But I'm not satisfied. First of all here is my finished code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void playOneGame();
char getUserResponseToGuess(int);
int getMidpoint(int, int);
bool shouldPlayAgain();

int main()
{
  do
  {
    playOneGame();
  } while (shouldPlayAgain());

  return 0;
}

void playOneGame()
{
  int min = 0;
  int max = 100;
  int num;
  char answer;
        
  cout << "Think of a number between 1 and 100." << endl;
  num = getMidpoint(min, max);
  answer = getUserResponseToGuess(num);
  
  while(answer != 'c')
  {
    if(answer == 'l')
    {
      max = num;
      max--;
      num = getMidpoint(min, max);
      answer = getUserResponseToGuess(num);
    }
    else if(answer == 'h')
    {
      min = num;
      min++;
      num = getMidpoint(min, max);
      answer = getUserResponseToGuess(num);
    }
  }
}

bool shouldPlayAgain()
{
  char playAgain;
  
  cout << "Great! Do you want to play again? (y/n): ";
  cin >> playAgain;
  
  if(playAgain == 'y')
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}

char getUserResponseToGuess(int guess)
{
  char input;
  cout << "Is it " << guess << "? (h/l/c):";
  cin >> input;
  
  return input;
}

int getMidpoint(int low, int high)
{
  double midP = (low + high) / 2;
  return midP;
}
```

This is the expected output:

> Think of a number between 1 and 100
>
> Is the number 50? (y/n/c): h
>
> Is the number 75? (y/n/c): l
>
> Is the number 62? (y/n/c): h
>
> Is the number 69? (y/n/c): h
>
> Is the number 72? (y/n/c):

This is the output MY program gets:

> Think of a number between 1 and 100
>
> Is the number 50? (y/n/c): h
>
> Is the number 75? (y/n/c): l
>
> Is the number 62? (y/n/c): h
>
> Is the number 68? (y/n/c): h
>
> Is the number 71? (y/n/c):

I just want to know why my numbers aren't calculating correctly. As you can see it is not by a huge difference but it still bothers me! I also can't change the int parameters, they must be ints!

Comment: Why did you expect it to round up? And how do you believe it impacts the function of the algorithm? You are doing a binary search either way.

Answer (score 1):

When `min` is 62 and `max` is 75, `mid` is computed as `(62 + 75)/2`, which is `137/2`. When you compute that using `(low + high)/2`, integer math is used to find the result, which is `68`. It's not clear to me why you expect it to be `69`.

```
double midP = (low + high) / 2;  // midP is 68, not 68.5
return midP;
```

Even if you change that to use floating point arithmetic,

```
double midP = 0.5*(low + high);  // midP is 68.5
return midP;
```

when it is returned from the function, it will be truncated since the return type of the function is `int`.

Comment: I expect it to be 69 because my teacher's sample output is that. They weren't really worried because it is not off by a lot but I was a bit frustrated that they wouldn't care to explain more. Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(low + high) / 2` is an integer, any fractional component is discarded. We call this *integer arithmetic*.

If you want to round such that an odd number value of `low + high` rounds up, then you could use

`double midP = std::round(0.5 * (low + high));`

My use of `0.5` forces the argument of `std::round` to be a `double` type. There are some hidden depths in this: for an IEEE754 double precision type, this multiplication of `0.5` will be exact up to the 52nd power of 2, and `std::round` will work perfectly in that range. Binary floating point arithmetic is a *very* complex topic. For an introduction, see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and reference I will look into this!